# What does this 'exif:GPSInfo: 8253' mean in ImageMagick identify command?

Tags: images, imagemagick, file-metadata

Totally love the tool and documentation and currently trying to use EXIF data to geotag my own pictures. **Just wondering what this exactly means:**

```
exif:GPSInfo: 8253
```

It pops up in the exif section when I use the command:

```
 identify -verbose me.jpg
```

It's a picture of myself, and I'm just trying to see if the meta-data contains my gps location trying to decipher that statement at the top.

**What exactly is the formatting behind that tag and does it provide any clue to GPS location?**

Comment: See [this answer](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/27719/what-does-gpsinfoifdpointer-5438-mean).

Comment: Tabish, while this question is certainly on-topic here at U&L, since it involves using software on a UNIX system, we have two comments (one offline and the above) that suggest a sister site [Photography](https://photo.stackexchange.com/) may have more experts to be able to answer your question. If, after looking around on that site, particularly at the link above from dirkt, you'd like us to move this question over there, let us know by flagging the post for moderator attention. Otherwise, it's perfectly acceptable to leave this question here. Thank you!